# C++ a quest. about syntax

Tags: c++

I've seen this line in the program. What does it mean?

```
int a = 0;
a ^= 1 << vector[i][j];
```

The second line. If anyone could explain this?

Comment: What part specifically? There's a few things going on there

Comment: What's the type of `vector`?

Comment: `<<` is [bitwise left shift operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) and `^=` is [compound exclusive OR operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are wondering about the operator `^=`

`^` is `XOR`
For example `x ^= x` would be equivalent to `x = x ^ x`, which is 0.

The code in the snippet above, performs a shift, then a XOR with the result and finally it assigns the result to `a`.

Example:
`a = 0`

If `vector[i][j]` is 2, then `1 << 2` (bitwise left  shift) is `100` in binary representation.

On the right hand side we have `100 ^ 000 == 100` and finally `a = 0b100`

Helpful links:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B
- https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=operator+%5E%3D

Answer (score 0):

`^` means *bitwise XOR*. `1 << n` means left shifting `1` by `n` times in bits. So if you have `1 << 2`, you start off with `001` in binary and left shift the `1` bit 2 times so it becomes `100` in binary which is 4 in decimal. When I say `001` or `100`, note that there are more leading `0`s until the full 32/64 bits is filled.